# increase and decrease the value of the day

Tags: java, date

i want to   increase and decrease the value of the day, with a random number of days, resulting always in a correct date. i want it to do it without calendar....is possiible this to be ? And how because i can not do it ..if someone can help ? i do this

```
public void addDaysInDate(int numberOfDates) {
    for (int i=1; i<= numberOfDates; i++)
    {
        day++;
        if(day>31)
        {
            month++;
            day=1;

            if (month>12)
            {
                year++;
                month=1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you wan to do it without `Calendar`?

Comment: Why don't you want to do it without a Calendar ? You need to handle (28, 29, 30, 31 days' month and other things

Comment: You need to adjust the code for months with different numbers of days. (And handle leap years)

Comment: And I imagine timezones will come and bite you in the arse at some point. Daylight savings time, etc. etc. Just use `Calendar`.

Comment: Unless this is for homework (if it is please specify this) then use the Calendar class or, even better IMHO, use JodaTime.

Comment: Consider going even further than `Calendar` and use the Joda libraries.

Comment: convert your date into long, then +/- `numOfDates * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000`?

Comment: i want to do it without calendar because the teacher want it without calendar...i do leap year in another with  this.year % 4 == 0 && (this.year % 100 != 0 || this.year % 400 == 0 i should call it in this ? i don t write all my program because is homework in university and i don t want it to see someone else my code

Comment: if you want i can sent all my code with private message to see what i do

Comment: Or if you are using Java 8, you can use the new `java.time` API classes

Comment: For a starting point, if you really only want to use standard mathematical functions, what is wrong with the current solution? PS. I'm guessing the parameter `numberOfDates` would be `numberOfDays` instead.

Comment: Another thing which can help, is to define a class named `Month`. That Month-class should have its number of days (`int`) defined in its constructor. This way, you can use `if`-statements to check whenever or not its a special month (i.e. leap year). Next to this, define a `Year`-class which initializes a boolean `leapyear` with it, being `false` or `true`. This can help Month-classes initialize their `int days` when you create them. Then use the main-class to calculate. That would be a nice solution for your teacher ;)